# How do I do WinJS events the angular way?

Tags: angularjs, win-universal-app, windows-10, winjs

There's a nice project for using Angular with WinJS controls together here: https://github.com/winjs/angular-winjs. I already have this working nicely in my app. However it doesn't really cover the use of angular for other parts of WinJS.

I am devloping on a windows 10 phone, and I have code like this:

```
 var app = WinJS.Application; 
 var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation; 
 app.onactivated = function (args) {
```

How can I modify my app.onactivated assigment to do things the angular way so I can use $providers and modify $scope variables and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $providers do you mean the services that angular offers(like $http,$location and so on)?

If so, you can put onactivated method inside the controller callback Definition function(see below codes) so that it can use the angular services.

JS:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["winjs"]);
var myController = myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.test = "The Scope.test has been changed!";
                });
            }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };
});
app.start();
})(angular);
```

HTML:

```
<body class="win-type-body" ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
<input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
   {{test}}
</div>
```

If not so, can you tell me what $providers are?